# MySQL tables or PHP explode for business hours

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to store business hours for 200+ unique businesses (and growing). Each business has varying hours and some are closed for lunch. In addition, a business might open at 8am one day and 9am on another. My initial thought was to build a MySQL table to handle this, but I then I considered storing it in a single cell and exploding the results out.  Exploding it out, I would store it something like this...

```
// "8:00-17:00|9:00-18:00|8:30-12:30,13:30-17:30|8:00-17:00|8:00-17:00|8:00-11:00||"

// For Day Data:             Explode "|"
// For Open/Close Data:      Explode "-"
// For Converting to am/pm:  Explode ":"
```

With single cell storage, it's array processing of data pulled from the clientData table (which has already been looped through). With a separate MySQL table, I'm looking at 7-14 rows per client (1,400 - 2,800 rows to start), depending on how its built. Is one way better than the other. How would you approach this?

Thanks!

## DESIRED OUTPUT

```
<div class="businessHours" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo 8:00-17:00"><strong>Monday:</strong> <span>8:00am-5:00pm</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu 9:00-18:00"><strong>Tuesday:</strong> <span>9:00am-6:00pm</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="We 8:30-12:30,13:30am-17:30"><strong>Wednesday:</strong> <span>8:30am-12:30pm, 1:30pm-5:30pm</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Th 9:00-18:00"><strong>Thursday:</strong> <span>9:00am-6:00pm</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Fr 8:00-17:00"><strong>Friday:</strong> <span>8:00am-5:00pm</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sa 8:00-1:00"><strong>Saturday:</strong> <span>8:00am-11am</span></time>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Su "><strong>Sunday:</strong> <span>Closed</span></time>
</div>
```

Comment: OK so your questions pretty and all, but it's down to you to carry out the appropriate research that helps you determine how to approach it. You can come back here and ask questions when you have a *specific* problem implementing your choice.

Comment: FWIW, if it was me, I'd go with your initial approach.

Comment: Are you going to need to do any sort of database queries using this data as criteria for join, filter, sort, etc.?

Comment: generally, if you're exploding data that you store in a single field, you should split the data into multiple fields instead. also, 2800 rows is not a significant amount and shouldn't be a concern here. as long as you index properly, hundreds of thousands or even hundreds of millions won't be a problem. take that and do what you will.

Comment: Thanks all! It sounds, at this point, that the table approach is the way to go. @Mike Brant: At this point, I can't think of a scenario I'd need to do more than output the data.

Comment: I would start to normalize the database. Having serialized data in a database cell is most likely an evidence for bad DB design.

Comment: yeah, you shouldn't be afraid to have as many small tables (that is, with few columns) as you need to normalize your data. that's the whole point of a relational database.

Comment: @sgroves I hadn't thought about that. OK. You've swayed me toward the table approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely use a table You can structure it two ways:

Vertical table:
id,Store ID, Day Of Week, Hours

Horizontal Table:
id,Store ID, M,T,W,TH,F,S,SU

There are pro's and cons to each, but following this approach will allow you to quickly list out all store hours for specific day only. Otherwise you would have to parse each row and explode it to the position of the day, or use a taxing like statement.

Comment: That's a really good point. Thanks for the thoughtful response. Now I just have to think through vertical vs horizontal. Thanks!

Comment: I personally think vertical is better. Only because it gives you a bit more flexibility and your queries are easier. But that is just my opinion. :D Let me know if I can help in any other way.

Comment: Thanks, John. I'm leaning toward vertical too. I was thinking if a business closed for lunch, I could have a row for the first set of hours and a row for the second, then sort by time while outputting that day. Otherwise, with horizontal, I have to delimit the times in the field and explode anyway.

Comment: Exactly! Good Luck :D

Answer (score 1):

I will put in a counter argument to the prevailing logic here.  If, as you say, you don't expect to have any need at some point in the future to query against specific business hour data, then I would suggest the whole collection of data is simply simply a property of the business and could be stored like this in a serialized manner.  This will make data write and retrieval for each business more optimal (eliminating more complex queries across a number of tables).

I would suggest you could also store the data in a serialized format (perhaps JSON, perhaps PHP's native serialization format), such that upon retrieval you can simply de-serialize the data and work with it.

Now, if you do think you will need to query the business hours info (i.e to display information like who is open now, who is open saturday, etc.) then I would take the advice of most other commentors on this thread and normalize the data.